# Custom Unwind Segue

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uistoryboardsegue

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034593/displacing-one-view-with-another-with-a-custom-segue-animation), I built a custom segue that displayed the destination view pushing down the source view from the top.  Now I am attempting to build an unwind segue that accomplishes the same animation, but in reverse.  Any idea how I would go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same custom segue class by performing the following check:

```
// check if the sourceViewController has been presented modally with a navigationController or just by itself.
UIViewController*presentingViewController = nil;
if ([sourceViewController.presentingViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
    presentingViewController = sourceViewController.presentingViewController;
}
else {
    presentingViewController = sourceViewController;
}

// check which animation we need to perform
if ([destinationViewController.presentingViewController isEqual:presentingViewController]) {
    // animation for unwind segue
    ...
}
else {
    // animation for presenting segue
    ...
}
```

Comment: What goes in the //animation for unwind segue? A UIStoryboardSegue instance?

Comment: It goes in the -perform method of your UIStoryboardSegue subclass. For more info about it, check developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIStoryboardSegue_Class/Reference/Reference.html. Your animation logic goes where I put the dots.

Comment: How do you handle the unwind segue animation logic, seeing as you obviously can't add the destination view as a subview of the source view?

Comment: You can animate the two views any way you want. When you're done you can call `[sourceViewController presentViewController:destinationViewController animated:NO]` and you're done.